# How to assign a particular column values of sharepoint List A 2010 from sharepoint ListB 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers, workflow-activity

I have two list in sharepoint 2010. In List A i have Assigned to field column(people or user group). In List B i have two fields Name and Email id column. I need the email id  values of List B should be assigned to (List A assigned field column) when adding new item in the List A.

How can i achieve this.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you want to do? Please describe structure of lists column by column and how list are connected. It is quite difficult to understand what you have and what you want from you description.

Answer (score 1):

An Assigned To field points to people and groups, not to another list. I see 3 ways to address your issue:

1. Instead of list B, create a SharePoint group, and have your Assigned To field point to that group.
2. Instead of an Assigned To field, use a lookup field that points to list B
3. A combination of both. For example use a lookup field that points to list B, then have a workflow copy the lookup value to the Assigned To field.

The choice will depend on your specific needs and constraints. The first solution is the easiest if it works in your case.

For the third option, use the e-mail address as key: copy the e-mail address of list B to the Assigned To field, SharePoint will find the related people.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am using the combination of both. I have lookup field that points to list B, then how to have a workflow copy the look up value to the Assigned To field.Please suggest how to do the workflow or any example.

Comment: @user876869 I have updated the post, let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I didnot  understand from your update...

Comment: Have you already used SharePoint Designer workflows, and in particular the action to update a field in the current item?

Comment: Thanks for your information. But my requirement is achieve through the Custom Action of Work Flow.

Comment: If you have specific requirements, I'd recommend that you update your question and select the relevant tags. Currently your question says "sharepoint designer".